# android intent-filter to listen for text data like sms inbox, email inbox, call logs, contacts

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like my app to be able to respond when an email inbox, sms inbox, call logs or contacts is open. For example, when a user clicks on the messaging icon it opens and then options menu should have my application name, so when they click my application, my activity should open.

my first attempt was to match on `scheme="SEND"`.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

which did work, but that was in Share Option Menu of Gallery. Now from Gallery when I open an image its Share menu has my activity, and I get the selected image into my application.

I want the same task for sms, contact, call log or an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sms I used:

```
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
```